# Illustrator Import/Insert acting weird

Tags: adobe-illustrator, image-quality, eps, error

What could be happening here when I import/insert this EPS file?

**Original EPS file:**

[image]

**EPS file when imported:**

[image]

Illustrator CC 2020

MacOS

Thank you!

Comment: It could be only a visual error, but all the anchor points are actually disposed this way. When I print or export as pdf it keeps this weird look.

Comment: Try to uncheck all snapping before you import it.

Comment: How is the original view generated? What if you try to open it in Photoshop?

Comment: @Lucian Original view was generated in Finder (MacOS). Tried it in a Windows explorer preview and it shows correctly.

Comment: @LeoNas disabling Snap to Pixel made it work! Thank you! 
**Extra information:** I figured this problem would only happen when I inserted it very small. When inserted larger, it would insert correctly.  That's why disabling Snap to Pixel makes sense.